# How to stop apps to request tracking on start of iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, permissions, bitrise

I am running `Flutter` integration tests on `iOS Simulator` using `Bitrise`.

Each time I need to start new instance of `iOS`. Due to Apple's privacy policy, I get the alert "Allow app to track your activity across other companies' apps and website?" on each new start of my app. And it blocks my tests.

I there a way to get rid of this alert on start of iOS Simulator?

How to disable the option with a single command?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is something called a "pre processor flag" that you can use to wrap the code that executes in a special kind of if statement. By default you can do:

```swift
#if DEBUG
    // do something if it's not production
#else
    // trigger the alert
#endif
```

However, that won't let you test it manually on your device unless you build a production release. You can add special flags to your test target's build settings that will only trigger in that target.

[image: Swift Compiler Flag]

Then we could write:

```swift
#if UITEST
  // do nothing here
#else
  // launch the alert
#endif
```